# how to disable a whole test suite based on a condition in nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to be able to disable a whole test suite based on a condition in nightwatch does anyone know how?

like I can use @disabled: true,

but what I really want is @disabled: true if browser is internet explorer

I want to disable a whole test suite if the browser is internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to disable/enable whole testcases in directory(eg: below code will change true to false) :

```
find tests/<your directory>  -type f -iname '*.js' -exec sed -i "s/@disabled': *true/@disabled': false/" {} +
```

if you want more specific , you should create a bash file with some --option. (if platform is IE then disable directoryA ,file090,file102...).

OR

Use difference config file(Nightwatch.js file)